# Object property returns as undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, properties, reference

working on a JavaScript project. This is a little bit complicated, I know, but I'm trying to basically verify, and act on, information from Object2 through a query of an associated property in Object1 (if that makes sense)...

```
Object1 = function() {
    this._list = [];
};
Object1.prototype.method1 = function(param) {
     if (param == "foo") { this.method2("foo"); }
};
Object1.prototype.method2 = function(param) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this._list.length; i++) {
        if (this._list[i]._name == param) {
            console.log(this._list[i]._name); // outputs "foo"
            return this._list[i]._name // **TypeError: value is undefined**
        }
    }
};

Object2 = function(name) {
    this._name = name || "foo";
}

var object = new Object1();
var foo = new Object2("foo");
object._list.push(foo);
object.method1("foo");
```

I know that's a bit convoluted. My problem though, is where it returns 
'param._name', it gives a TypeError. However, in the previous line, when I send it to the console, it comes out fine.

I admit that I'm a bit new to JavaScript, and even newer to OOP, so if this is a dumb, or nonsensical question, please go easy on me!

Any ideas? All ideas and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, place your method invocations below your method definitions.

Comment: Yes, the `this.object`, `var foo =` and `== item` parts are wrong. Could you please fix those before asking your question, so that you actual problem is at least reproducable?

Comment: Edited to be a little bit cleaner - sorry about that

Comment: Ah, that looks better now. But as soon as I fix `object1`->`object` and `.list`->`._list` (2x), it just works - without a type error.

Comment: Oh hell, why can I not type this code example correctly? I have those same corrections in my production code (and will add them here as well) but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object1 Method1 should have looked like this:

```
Object1.prototype.method1 = function(param) {
    if (param == "foo") { return this.method2("foo"); }
};
```

Notice the **return** in there. Thank you to everyone who attempted to answer, and for your help. This post was a trainwreck from the beginning - my own fault - and I apologize for that, but I do appreciate your help and kindness in helping me work through it.

Answer (score 0):

I did same corrections in the code, try it:

```
Object1 = function() {
    this._list = [];
};
Object1.prototype.method1 = function(param) {
     if (param == "foo") { this.method2("foo"); }
};
Object1.prototype.method2 = function(param) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this._list.length; i++) {
        var item = this._list[i];
        if (item._name == param) {
            console.log(item._name); 
            return item._name;
        }
    }
};

Object2 = function(name) {
    this._name = name || "foo";
}

var object = new Object1();
var foo = new Object2("foo");
object._list.push(foo);
object.method1("foo");
```

Comment: I edited the code in the example to better reflect what I'm actually trying to do. I apologize for the sloppiness - I'm still fairly new at this